# T-SQL COUNT(*) counts NULLS but I don't want to count NULLS in row count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario where I'm trying not to count a row where it has a zero, blank or NULL. But I'm not sure how to. I have used ISNULL to replace it with blank but the result shows zero. I don't want zero because it messes up my averages etc. The screen shot below should show 17 in the bottom as total but it's showing 18 because it's counting the null as row count. This null row has an N/A as a value in the data set but my count counts it as a row. I'm using count(*) because I have many other columns so I can not change the count(*). Any ideas on how to show the total as 17 instead of 18?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: `COUNT` already automatically ignores `NULL` values, all aggregate functions do, and your data contains no rows with `0`; though a simple `WHERE` would also filter them out from the results test. What is the actual attempt you made?

Comment: When it encounter 7/17 the results get wrong. It's counting 7/18 if you look at the last value in the screen shot below. It should be 7/17 as the arrows show. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you've moved the goalposts, you should be asking a new question.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Since you've posted images we have to assume that all columns are data type `pixel` and that you want a `pixel` result. Data as text, with input, desired output and DDL, helps us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some SQL implementations (I think this is also proper ANSI standard but don't know that for sure) exhibit a different behaviour for `COUNT(*)` VS `COUNT(field)`.

The former will include NULLs, the latter will exclude them.

Comment: Count(field) worked. But not sure it will affect the other columns. Thank you

Comment: It affected the other counts for the same column. For example now the count is 17 and there are 7 occurrences of 5's so the division for 7/17 should equal to 0.41176470588 but it returns 0.388889. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. I used a filter to filter out N/A which works fine so far. Thank you

Comment: Actually it does not work. The filter in the where clause messed up other column values for calculations like Count(*), Sum, AVG etc. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It's hard to tell, would ask you to provide a mock-up dataset that better represents your real table, and with which we can understand the conflicts you are facing.
From the bits of information you left in the comments to the various proposed answers, I would guess you need the entire row-set so no `WHERE` clause for you but rather lots of `COUNT(CASE WHEN condition(s) THEN field_to_count) END)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use SUM like this

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(testeq4,'') <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: `testeq4` is clearly an `int`, not a `varchar`, so why return `''` when it's `NULL`, which would be converted to `0`, and then compare it to `''`, which would also be converted to `0`?

Comment: Maybe it's not possible? I have 18 rows for many other columns so I get 18 but for this column I don't want to count NULL or zero. If I count or replace it with zero it will mess up my average calculations. Any ideas?

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN nullif(testeq4, 'N/A') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) or COUNT(NULLIF(testeq4, 'N/A'))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(TestQ4,0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```